# Geometrical optics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, reflection, geometric-optics

I Just wanna know the general approach to these problems,

Two plane mirrors of length L are separated by distance L and a man $M_2$​ is standing at distance L from the connecting line of mirrors as shown in the figure. A man $M_1$is walking in a straight line at distance 2 L parallel to mirrors at speed u, then man $M _2$ ​ at O will be able to see image of $M_1$ for time = ?

[image]

I have tried drawing some triangles to check out similarity but couldn't find a correct solution. I passed the incident ray through the corners of mirror.

Please help further how to proceed.

Comment: Can be done using field of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M2 should be able to see the reflection of M1 in the top mirror whenever a line can be drawn from M1 to M2 via a bounce off the top mirror.  This is exactly equivalent to drawing a straight line from M2 to M1', where M1' is on the opposite side of the mirror plane at the "reflected position" of M1.  If the line misses the mirrors by passing through the gap between the two mirrors, M2 cannot see the reflection of M1 in the mirrors.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help, was able to solve the problem.

Comment: Good to hear.  You can click on the check mark to indicate that you've accepted the answer.  Up and down arrows are upvotes and downvotes.